# Duplicate authorities in spring security authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm using Spring security to provide authentication and authorization for my webapp. I use JWT as OAuth2 access token. But I found that the authentication has two authorities, one is `authentication.authorities`. The other one is `authentication.userAuthentication.authorities`.

[image: two authorities]

Because of the large number of authorities, so the JWT's payload is too big (30kb).

Is there any way that I can have only one authorities in authentication?

Answer (score 1):

The two authorities are shared the same list data.

**UnmodifiableRandomAccessList** only a wrapper, it will only refer the origin list. You dig into the two authorities, then you will see the same instance id of the list.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your support! So I need to thin the authorites list to make JWT's playload smaller?