# Spring security has authorities on Authentication and on the Principal - why and which one to use?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'am aware of the question [Duplicate authorities in spring security authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63772495/duplicate-authorities-in-spring-security-authentication) but it's scope is much narrow.

My question is, if the idea of both should be "they should share the exact same information" - why is there no contract enforcing the very same? For example neither`AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider` nor `DaoAuthenticationProvider` is providing that implementation to enforce that those are the same. Actually, they both do not care about all having the authorities set on the principal in the first stem.

So for example, if i add the Authority FOO to the token inside my Filter, they would never be set on the Principal/UserDetails, just stay on the Authentication container.

Reading the javaDoc of `org.springframework.security.core.Authentication#getAuthorities` it seems it is planned that this the source of truth for checking if the principal has any authorities.

But the very same goes for `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails#getAuthorities`.

AFAICS it is usually much more practical to use the Authorities withing the principal, since one can keep the principal of the same type for all the different providers that might have authenticated the user. This helps when one consumes the principal via `@AuthenticationPrincipal` in controllers and such.

The concrete question is thus:

- If so, what ensures that those two authority lists are the same? (both as contract and in the spring security default implementation)
- if that is not present, which of those is considered the "real source of truth"

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you use spring security expressions like `hasAnyAuthority` or others, spring will use the authorities on the authentication object, not the user principal. You can see an example of this in `SecurityExpressionsRoot.java:getAuthoritySet()`.

To account for this the base implementation of `AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider` copies all authorities from the `UserDetails` after loading them to the `Authentication` object it returns. This is done in the method `createSuccessAuthentication`.

Therefore if one is to implement its own provider one has to make sure the authorities are set on the outer `Authentication` object.
So for spring security it seems the `Authentication.authorities` is the one that's relevant, not sure about the 'which is the one point of truth' part though. You could argue that the one on the `UserDetails` is the source of truth since `AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider` implementation copy those over to the `Authorization`. On the other hand you could argue Spring security uses `Authentication.authorities` to evaluate expressions, so this is it.